# Unable to append in order

Tags: python, opencv, imread

```
import os
train_dir = "/Images/train/"
data = []
for i in os.listdir(train_dir):
    path = os.path.join(train_dir, i)
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    print(i)
    data.append(img)
```

My train directory has 49000 images in order img(1), img(2), ..., img(49000)
I want to append these images in this order only but they are getting appended in a different order (as shown in the image).
Any help?

[image: I have printed the order in which they are getting appended]

I want to append them as img(1).png, img(2).png, img(3).png, and so on.

Comment: Just sort the names...

Comment: listdir has listed all files using string comparison sorting, you need to sort the list after appending using custom logic

Comment: if you know the file names are going to be in that order, why dont you have a for loop and load the files using the i from for loop as the number

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorting and then appending worked!

Answer (score 1):

Using the sorted method helped me.

```
data = []
train_dir = "/Images/train/"
files = os.listdir(train_dir)
files = sorted(files ,key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))

for i in (files):
    path = os.path.join(train_dir, i)
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    data.append(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

So all you want to do is to list the images name in a python list. Which is filenames in my solution. Python list has function called sort() which will sort all the images name. Your new filenames list will be in sorted order relative to your images name that are there inside your directory. So, iterating through the list, you will be getting the sorted images name.

```py
train_dir = "/Images/train/"
filenames = [img for img in os.listdir(train_dir)]
filenames.sort()
data = []
for i in filenames:
    path = os.path.join(train_dir, i)
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    print(i)
    data.append(img)
```

Comment: While this vode may solve the question, it is always necessary to add a description about why and how the code solves it.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I have updated my solution :) Hope it will help you better, reply to this if any problem occurs again

Comment: The code is still providing the same output. Instead I have used the sorted() method and it worked.